# SQL Select Between intervals

Tags: sql, select, intervals, between

I have a list of people who have completed training sessions. I need to select all the people who have completed sessions by intervals of 5. So the list would only pull the rows when a person has reached 5, 10, 15, 20 sessions and so on.

```
Name           Sessions
John Smith     5
Bill Smith     10
Joe Smith      15
```

Is there a quick way of doing this or do I have to

```
SELECT WHERE sessions = 5 OR 10 OR 15
```

Comment: what version of sql? You'll basically just check if modulo 5 == 0

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
SELECT col FROM table WHERE sessions % 5 = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

use the modulo / remainder operator from your RDBMS.

for example in **[postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-math.html)**

```
  SELECT *
  FROM YourTable
  WHERE sessions % 5 = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the modulo operator (`%`) like this:

```
SELECT Stuff FROM Table WHERE (sessions % 5) = 0
```

The modulo operator calculates a remainder. When the remainder of `sessions` divided by 5 is zero, that means that `sessions` is divisible by 5.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean where the number of sessions they have done is divisible by 5.

```
SELECT P.PersonId, Count(S.SessionId)
FROM Person P
INNER JOIN Sesssion S ON S.PersonId = P.PersonId
GROUP BY P.PersonId
HAVING Count(S.SessionId) % 5 = 0
```

The HAVING is the important bit here.

Comment: Ah - seems that's not want he wants.
He may do after some normalisation.